# How to call a function after a component has been unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that will call browserHistory.push(url) at some point, and I need to call a function after the component has been unmounted and the next component has mounted. At the moment, I'm using setTimeout because it seems that unmounting a component fires all the setTimeouts immediately. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please provide your code for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through the lifecycle docs of react https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

The main two methods are for your use is componentDidMount. You can call your function inside this method of the next component that renders after pushing the URL.
It is obvious that your old component was unmounted at that time.

I can only suggest this approach at this time. Maybe your function has different dependencies which require its call in the old component itself.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what that function does, but the best is to call it within the `componentDidMount` in your next component.

Comment: Or call `componentDidUnmount`

Comment: @ritaj React has only `componentWillUnmount` and not `componentDidUnmount`. The reason is that they want you to unbind all handlers before they remove the component from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your parent component for calling that function, if you do conditional rendering. 
You can also use `componentDidMount` in next component as @Hasan said.